# Desde función en Javascript se intenta incorporar un evento submit y que los datos que ingresa el usuario aparezcan en el DOM o al menos por consola

Tags: javascript, formularios, function, submit, listener

En este código se intenta incorporar un evento submit desde la función validarFormulario pero no hace nada... al parecer funciona bien pero trato de que aparezca por consola algo y no logro aún comprender... pensé que era que no existía el id en el HTML pero si existe y lo que deseo es que los datos que introduzca el usuario aparezcan en el DOM o al menos por consola

```
const categoria = ["REMERAS", "JEANS","VESTIDOS"];

class Producto {
    constructor(codigo, nombre, precio, categoria){
        this.codigo = parseInt(codigo);
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio =(precio);
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
}

const productos = [];
productos.push(new Producto(0001,"Remera Básica", 1500, categoria[0]));
productos.push(new Producto(0002," Remera Denim", 1700, categoria[0]));
productos.push(new Producto(1001,"Jean Clásico", 5000, categoria[1]));
productos.push(new Producto(1002,"Jean Oxford", 6800, categoria[1]));
productos.push(new Producto(2001,"Vestido Corto", 3500, categoria[2]));
productos.push(new Producto(2002, "Vestido Largo", 5560, categoria[2]));

console.log(productos);

let divProd= document.getElementById("productos");

for (const producto of productos) {
        let divProducto= document.createElement("div");
        divProducto.innerHTML=`<h2>Producto: ${producto.nombre}</h2>
                                <h2>Precio: $ ${producto.precio} </h2>
                                <button>Comprar</button><hr> `;        
        divProd.append(divProducto);
}

/*-------------HTML CONTACTO   array + evento -------------*/

class Contactos{
    constructor(nombre,email,telefono){
        this.nombre=nombre.toUpperCase();
        this.email=email;
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }
}

const contactos=[];
let datosContactos=document.getElementById('formulario');
datosContactos.addEventListener("submit", validarFormulario);

function validarFormulario(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("Formulario Enviado");    
}







<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--link css bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!--link css propio-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css">

    <script src="../JS/main.js"></script>

    <title>CHITA Indumentaria - Contacto</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
                    <img src="../imagenes/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100" height="100"
                        class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Productos
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/remeras.html">Remeras</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/jeans.html">Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/vestidos.html">Vestidos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="../paginas/preguntas-frecuentes.html">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="../paginas/contacto.html">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form id="formulario">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Teléfono">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </form>
      
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
            <p>aqui ira el pie de pagina</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--link JS bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeramente agrega a tus inputs el atributo `name` que identificará los campos del formulario en tu objeto:

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="nombreCompleto">
<input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
<input type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono">
<input type="submit" value="Enviar">
```

Luego modifica tu función `validarFormulario` para obtener el valor de los campos del `form`:

```
function validarFormulario(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    const datos = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    console.log(datos);
    e.target.reset();   // Opcionalmente para borrar el formulario
}
```

Con eso ya tendrás en la variable `datos` todo lo que se submite en el formulario. Te adjunto tu ejemplo completo. Ten en cuenta que he agregado un div con el id `productos` ya que no existía en el html y causaba error en la mitad del script. También trata de poner la etiqueta `script` al final del body para que evites posibles errores de que se ejecute tu código `js` antes de que el navegador haya parseado todo el html.

```js
const categoria = ["REMERAS", "JEANS","VESTIDOS"];

class Producto {
    constructor(codigo, nombre, precio, categoria){
        this.codigo = parseInt(codigo);
        this.nombre = nombre;
        this.precio =(precio);
        this.categoria = categoria;
    }
}

const productos = [];
productos.push(new Producto(0001,"Remera Básica", 1500, categoria[0]));
productos.push(new Producto(0002," Remera Denim", 1700, categoria[0]));
productos.push(new Producto(1001,"Jean Clásico", 5000, categoria[1]));
productos.push(new Producto(1002,"Jean Oxford", 6800, categoria[1]));
productos.push(new Producto(2001,"Vestido Corto", 3500, categoria[2]));
productos.push(new Producto(2002, "Vestido Largo", 5560, categoria[2]));

// console.log(productos);

let divProd= document.getElementById("productos");

for (const producto of productos) {
        let divProducto= document.createElement("div");
        divProducto.innerHTML=`<h2>Producto: ${producto.nombre}</h2>
                                <h2>Precio: $ ${producto.precio} </h2>
                                <button>Comprar</button><hr> `;        
        divProd.append(divProducto);
}



/*-------------HTML CONTACTO   array + evento -------------*/

class Contactos{
    constructor(nombre,email,telefono){
        this.nombre=nombre.toUpperCase();
        this.email=email;
        this.telefono=telefono;
    }
}


const contactos=[];
let datosContactos=document.getElementById('formulario');
datosContactos.addEventListener("submit", validarFormulario);

function validarFormulario(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    const formData = new FormData(e.target);
    const datos = Object.fromEntries(formData.entries());
    console.log(datos);
    e.target.reset();   // Opcionalmente para borrar el formulario
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <!--link css bootstrap-->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">

        <!--link css propio-->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../CSS/main.css">

    <title>CHITA Indumentaria - Contacto</title>
</head>

<body>
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            <div class="container-fluid">
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="../index.html">
                    <img src="../imagenes/logo.png" alt="logo" width="100" height="100"
                        class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
                </a>
                <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse"
                    data-bs-target="#navbarNavDropdown" aria-controls="navbarNavDropdown" aria-expanded="false"
                    aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                    <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
                </button>
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav">
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link active" aria-current="page" href="../index.html">Inicio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                            <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" role="button"
                                data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">
                                Productos
                            </a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/remeras.html">Remeras</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/jeans.html">Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="../paginas/productos/vestidos.html">Vestidos</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="../paginas/preguntas-frecuentes.html">Preguntas Frecuentes</a>
                        </li>
                        <li class="nav-item">
                            <a class="nav-link" href="../paginas/contacto.html">Contacto</a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <main>
        <form id="formulario">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Nombre y Apellido" name="nombreCompleto">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Email" name="email">
            <input type="text" placeholder="Teléfono" name="telefono">
            <input type="submit" value="Enviar">
       </form>
       <div id="productos"></div>
      
    </main>
    <footer>
        <div class="p-3 mb-2 bg-secondary text-white">
            <p>aqui ira el pie de pagina</p>
        </div>
    </footer>

    <!--link JS bootstrap-->
    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
        integrity="sha384-ka7Sk0Gln4gmtz2MlQnikT1wXgYsOg+OMhuP+IlRH9sENBO0LRn5q+8nbTov4+1p"
        crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
        <script src="./script.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```